# Is it possible for sendTransaction to return an empty hash from MetaMask while isSuccess is true

Tags: metamask, react, wagmi

Our app is using React + Wagmi + prepare hooks.

One MetaMask user had an issue where their transaction completed successfully, but `DoThisThing` was never called. Code is simplified, but wondering if anyone has experienced Wagmi + MetaMask broadcasting a successful transaction while *not* returning the hash and/or isSuccess. Is this possible?

```
const { data, isSuccess, sendTransaction } = useSendTransaction(config);

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess && data?.hash) {
    DoThisThing({ hash: data.hash });
  }
}, [data?.hash, isSuccess]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wagmi [useSendTransaction() version 1.4.3](https://1.x.wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useSendTransaction) you can use callback function **onSuccess()** like this:

```
const { data, isSuccess, sendTransaction } = useSendTransaction({
    ...config,
    onSuccess(data) {
       DoThisThing({ hash: data.hash });
    },
});
```